# Java Networking - Unexpected Vector Behavior

Tags: java, networking, vector, server, client

Basically I have a 2D Vector representing player position resting on a server that I want to increment using the clients ( so they can move ). Having no problems at all with server/client communication and a command interface similar to bash to send comprehensive and easily deconstruct able commands between the server and the client :

**/command -param1 value1 -param2 value2**

I can successfully connect new clients , ping the server and get live information from the server. My problem comes when trying to set the speed of a client , which causes the Vector to stutter everywhere while the actual position and speed im getting from the server remains at 0. To try and debug this weird behavior I decided to add a line of code adding 0.0001f to the x position of the client each server tick. This works and the vector moves on the client screen except from the fact that **it reaches 256.0 then stops moving**.

If I increment a bigger value the same thing happens , but this time the vector reaches some large value before stopping.

I would post my code here but there is so much of it and I have absolutely no idea what could be causing this.

Could it be because I try to send numeric values using text ?
Could it be because the server isnt running at a constant tickrate ?
Could it be because I store the client info in a hashmap ?

This error makes no sense to me , I've been revising my code for hours now without finding anything. Its probably because im not familiar with the server / client architecture but I have to be missing something crutial here.

Comment: You need to post the code if you want a response

Comment: I highly doubt its a code error and probably something related to server / client exchanges. I mean , the code supposed to make the vector move around only increments the x value each iteration , there are no conditions that should be causing it to stop happening until the server stops , its not tied to the delta time , its just x+=0.01f.

Comment: If the error is within my code Ill find it myself just by looking / trying again from scratch , What I wonder is if its something like weird behavior floats might encounter when parsed from plaintext and passed from server to client. My code may very well be invalid but that simple operation should not cause trouble.

It could be that the float doesnt increment past 256 on the server OR that the client isnt getting any values higher than 256 , none of which make sense because I can increment a higher value and the float gets stuck somewhere else yet the client is able to get that position.

Comment: This is fantasy. Debug your code.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys !